# plotting dynamic data using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I'm writing an application do display data that changes dynamically (the data being read from a socket).

As a dummy case, I try to draw a sine with an amplitude multiplied by 1.1 each second:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)


for i in xrange(100):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    time.sleep(1)
    y=y*1.1
```

This obviously not the way do it, but it shows my intentions.

How can it be done correctly?

**EDIT:**
The following is the traceback output of the code suggested in @mskimm answer:

```
plt.show() #Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-5-ed773f8e3e84>", line 7, in update
    plt.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 466, in draw
    get_current_fig_manager().canvas.draw()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 240, in draw
    tkagg.blit(self._tkphoto, self.renderer._renderer, colormode=2)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/tkagg.py", line 12, in blit
    tk.call("PyAggImagePhoto", photoimage, id(aggimage), colormode, id(bbox_array))
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

**EDIT 2:**

it turns out that same code works when run in qtconsole... (any idea why?)
How ever, each print rescaling to plot, so the "animation effect" is missing.
I try to use `plt.autoscale_view(False,False,False)` but that just caused no plot at all.

Comment: Are you trying to show this as a somewhat 'animated' plot, or are you looking for 100 different plots here?

Comment: @davef yes, an animated plot. sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are better ways to do this using the [matplotlib animation API](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/animation/simple_anim.html),
but here's a quick and dirty approach:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.ion()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_autoscale_on(True)
line, = ax.plot(x, y)

for i in xrange(100):
    line.set_ydata(y)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view(True,True,True)
    plt.draw()
    y=y*1.1
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

The key steps are:

1. Turn on interactive mode with `plt.ion()`.
2. Keep track of the line(s) you want to update, and overwrite their data instead of calling `plot` again.
3. Give Python some time to update the plot window by calling `plt.pause`.

I included the code to autoscale the viewport, but that's not strictly necessary.

Comment: when removing the autoscale - it's just what I was looking for, thanks, and have my virtual +1 :)

Comment: +1, This is much better. Because I didn't know `ion`, I implemented several programs using `thread`.

Answer (score 3):

Is it hard to apply `animated`? How about using `thread` that updates the figure.
Even though `plt.show()` is blocking, the `thread` will update the figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import threading

def update(x, y):
    for i in xrange(100):
        # clear
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(x, y)
        # draw figure
        plt.draw()
        time.sleep(1)
        y=y*1.1

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)

# use thread
t = threading.Thread(target=update, args=(x, y))
t.start()

plt.show() # blocking but thread will update figure.
```

Comment: This code throws an exception (within the new thread). A traceback added to my original post. @mskimm

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to redraw the plot from scratch. Surely it's slower than updating it point by point, but if you have not many points, the overhead is negligible.

```
from IPython import display
from matplolib import pyplot as plt


def dynamic_plot(X,Y, figsize=[10,5], max_x=None, min_y=None, max_y=None):
    '''plots dependency between X and Y dynamically: after each call current graph is redrawn'''
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(figsize)
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(X,Y)
    if max_x: 
        plt.gca().set_xlim(right=max_x)
    if min_y: 
        plt.gca().set_ylim(bottom=min_y)
    if max_y: 
        plt.gca().set_ylim(top=max_y)
        
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
```

And the demo use for jupyter notebook:

```
import time

X=[]
Y=[]
for i in range(10):
    X.append(i)
    Y.append(i**.5)
    dynamic_plot(X,Y,[14,10], max_x=10, max_y=4)  
    time.sleep(0.3)
```